# Three times Gutenberg, why three tags, should they be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I just came across a set of tags that I wonder if they should be Synonyms of each other?

- 63 questions with [wordpress-gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-gutenberg) Questions related to WordPress Gutenberg editor.
- 43 questions with [gutenberg-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg-blocks) tag has no usage guidance
- 75 questions with [gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg) tag has no usage guidance

However

- 21 questions [have all three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg-blocks+wordpress-gutenberg+gutenberg)
- 28 have both [gutenberg and gutenberg-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg-blocks+gutenberg)
- 53 use [gutenberg and wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg+wordpress)

I would think gutenberg should be made a Synonyms of wordpress-gutenberg.  Not sure about the guttenberg-blocks.

Comment: The existence of Project Gutenberg and the possible confusion it could cause, actually came up in [a discussion about the project name](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/4681). Unfortunately they decided to continue using the name, despite the drawbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Five of the questions tagged with [gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg) are related to Project Gutenburg, and is not related to the new Wordpress editor codenamed "Gutenberg". I've re-tagged them with [project-gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-gutenberg).

I have reviewed six questions tagged [gutenberg-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg-blocks) [without mentioning Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgutenberg-blocks%5d%20-%5bwordpress%5d%20-%5bwordpress-gutenberg%5d%20-wordpress%20is%3aq&mixed=0), and found out Gutenberg has the concept of "blocks", which can be programatically created for use in the Gutenberg editor. We shall leave this tag alone for now?

Questions tagged [gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg) without any mention of Wordpress gives [three results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bgutenberg%5D+-%5Bwordpress%5D+-%5Bwordpress-gutenberg%5D+-%5Bgutenberg-blocks%5D+-wordpress+is%3Aq&mixed=0):

- [How to filter Taxonomies using Rust-based Gutenberg / Tera?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489873)

  - Plugin renamed to [Zola](https://github.com/getzola/zola) - retagged [zola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zola)
- [Gutenberg extend blocks add new class name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50435326)

  - Seems WP-related
- [React pass data attribute to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50432651)

  - Doesn't seem WP-related - tag removed

Let me know if it is now safe to merge [gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg) into [wordpress-gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-gutenberg) or vice-versa.

---

I'm in favour of merging this early, as Wordpress is widely used.

```
updating post history, 70 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 69 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 32 rows affected
destroying 'gutenberg': [gutenberg] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 96
tag remapping of [wordpress-gutenberg] and [gutenberg] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
20 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym gutenberg -> wordpress-gutenberg was approved!
```

Comment: I would think merge into wordpress-gutenberg would be better, as it obviously confused with project gutenberg otherwise.